# Using Cauchy integral formula on $\int_C \frac{dz}{z(2z+1)}$ for the unit circle contour C

Tags: complex-analysis

There is an integral $\int_C \frac{dz}{z(2z+1)}$ where C is the unit circle contour. I suppose that $f(z) = \frac{1}{2z+1}$ is analytic in the whole complex plane except for $z=-1/2$ and +/-infinity and the point $z = 0$ is clearly within the unit circle contour C. Then I apply the Cauchy integral formula, integral = $(2\pi i)f(0)=2\pi i$. However my textbook says the integral is equal to zero. So it seems that I apply the integral formula in a wrong way! Any comments on my work?

Comment: There are two residues inside that contour. One way to approach this is to use partial fractions.

Comment: If $z_0 \in \{0, -1/2\}$ then $z_0$ is a pole of $\frac{1}{z(2z+1}$ and $ |z_0|<1.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two simple poles inside the circle, $z=0$ and $z=-\frac{1}{2}$. Setting $g(z)\equiv \frac{1}{z(2z+1)}$,

$$\text{Res}(g,0)=\lim_{z \to 0} z\;g(z)=1$$

$$\text{Res}\left(g,-\frac{1}{2}\right)=\lim_{z \to -\frac{1}{2}} \left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)\;g(z)=-1\;.$$

The sum of the two residues is equal to 0 and so is the integral, by the residue theorem.

Comment: Notice I've called $f(z)=\frac{1}{z(2z+1)}\;.$ I should have called it $g(z)$ because $f(z)$ in your calculation with Cauchy's integral formula is $\frac{1}{2z+1}$, and the other $f(z)$ you left out is $\frac{1}{2z}$, I've applied the residue theorem, but the result is the same.

Comment: so if there are two poles than i cant just let $f(z) = \frac{1}{2z+1}$?

Comment: Correct. You have to use Cauchy's integral formula twice. The first time, with $f(z)=\frac{1}{2z+1}$ and a contour around $z=0$ only, you found $f(0)=1$. The second time, with $h(z)=\frac{1}{2z}$ and a contour around $z=-\frac{1}{2}$ only, you get $h\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)=-1$. $f(0)$ and $h(0)$ are the residues of the original function $g(z)=\frac{1}{z(2z+1)}$ at $z=0$ and $z=-\frac{1}{2}$ respectively, and, by the residue theorem, must be summated and multiplied by $2πi$ to obtain the value of the integral.

Comment: There's obviously a typo above. It's $h\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)$, not $h(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_C \frac{dz}{z(2z+1)}$$
$$\frac{1}{z(2z+1)}= \frac{A}{z}+\frac{B}{(2z+1)}$$
$$\frac{1}{z(2z+1)}= \frac{1}{z}- \frac{2}{(2z+1)}$$
$$\frac{1}{z(2z+1)}= \frac{1}{z}- \frac{1}{(z+1/2)}$$
$$I=2i\pi ( 1-1)=0$$